# getting date in nodejs

Tags: node.js, date, xlsx, node-modules

Here iam uploading my excel file(xslx format) using nodejs.In that iam passing dates dd-mm-yy .after uploading my response has showing different date which means in milliseconds I think so.Then how to get our date value from xlsx excel using nodejs

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Node.JS is a JavaScript environment. So that, if you have milliseconds, you can simply do

```
var myDate = new Date(1452188743178);
console.log(myDate); // Thu Jan 07 2016 18:45:43 GMT+0100
```

`myDate` is now a standard JavaScript [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: No still same, i have tried this...when iam uploading date in excel sheet as 09/01/2016 it converts it as like this  Sat Jan 01 42614 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)So in my db it just get updating like this:  0000-00-00 00 :00:00.Any idea?

Comment: By giving like this  yyyy,mm,dd in startdate column of excel sheet ,it gets right date and updating in database.Is there any other way in handle from server side,as user friendly?